# How to send cookies received in axios get() in following post() on react-native?

Tags: cookies, react-native, axios

**Summary:**
Cookies received in previous *get* call not send with following *post* command.

**Details:**
I am using the following sequence of calls to login into the backend.

```
axios.get(Url.csrfToken(), { withCredentials: true })
        .then(response => response.data)
        .then(token => axios.post(Url.authenticate(), { username, password }, {
                headers: {
                    'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'crsf-token' : `${token.csrfToken}`
                },
                withCredentials: true
            })
        )
        .then(response => console.log('completed'))
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
```

Cookies returned in `set-cookie` in response headers for *get()* is required by *post()*.

**But post() does not have any cookie in its header**, leading to failure.

How could I fix it, please help?

**Environment**

- react: 16.0.0-alpha.12
- react-native: 0.47.2
- iOS Simulator - version 10.0